# ng-bind-html not recognizing ID names

Tags: ng-bind-html, ngsanitize

I'm using ng-bind-html and it pulls in the HTML with class names, but the id names are all missing.  What is causing this?

actual code example:

```
service partial example

  var assets = {
      'sampleInvoice': '<div id="invoice-div"><table id="invoice-table-id" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody>......
    }

  controller portion:

    $scope.invoiceDetails = function(params) {
        console.log("Here I am ");
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'invoice-details-modal',
            controller: 'invoiceDetailsCtrl',
            windowClass: 'invoice-details-modal',
            resolve: {
                invoice: function resolveInvoiceTemplate($q) {
                    return $q.resolve($templateCache.get("sampleInvoice"));
                }
            }
        });
```

HTML Part

```
  <div ng-bind-html="invoice"></div>
```

What it's producing:

```
<div><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr valign="top"><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td class="invoice-logo-td"><div class="invoice-logo">....
```

Notice the class names are there, but the ids are gone.  Now, I can switch all the ids to classes as a work around, but it seems like it should be able to recognize id names as well.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  (Yes, I injected ngSanitize)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Stripping id's from elements in an intentional sanitation. You can see the original commit that caused this back in [v1.0.0-rc2](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/2bbced212e2ee93948c45360fee00b2e3f960392).

The reasoning isn't given in the commit, but a later issue filed against angularjs about [striping id's from img tags](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11942) explains this:

> the reason why we strip out `id` and `name` is that browsers put them on `window`
>
> `<div id="angular">` would overwrite the `window.angular` with an element. This is considered a security issue and so we don't allow it.
>
> — *mhevery*